# MongoDB cursor is slow when fetching second batch

Tags: mongodb

I'm seeing an odd behavior when iterating over a cursor: fetching the **second** batch is very slow (several seconds or more). The first batch is reasonably fast, as are all the batches after the second one. And the other odd thing is, I can make this behavior go away by increasing the batch size (default is 100, I increased it to 800).

```
    MongoCursor<Document> it = collection
            .find()
            .batchSize(800)
            .projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("year")))
            .iterator();
    int count = 0;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(""+count+" : "+it.next());
        count++;
    }
```

For the above example, I'm using a DB with about half a million records. If I don't set the batch size, it pauses after printing the 100th record, then continues normally.

Can someone explain why this is happening? Is it a bug in the server or the client? Does it indicate a problem with the way I set up my DB?

Server version: 4.0.10

Java client version: 3.10.1